# Verify that an NServiceBus saga does not reply to originator

Tags: unit-testing, nservicebus, nservicebus-sagas

What is the best way to test that a saga has not replied to originator?

I see that using NServiceBus.Testing I can call Saga.ExpectReplyToOriginator, but I'm not seeing anything like "ExpectNotReplyToOriginator".  I tried using .ExpectNotSend() and .ExpectNotPublish() and neither seems to fail where I'd expect it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current version of NServiceBus.Testing doesn't support what you are looking for.

I opened an issue here: https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.Testing/issues/40

When it will be completed, I'll let you know

Comment: @ksigmund `ExpectNotReplyToOriginator` is available in NServiceBus.Testing 5.2